# Is there a current sense coil inside this ELCB?

Tags: rcd

Is there a current differential sense coil inside this ELCB (Earth Leakage Circuit Breaker) just like GFCI or RCD? I took it from a unit and I dont want to break it apart to peek I cant find any schematic in the part no. I read in wiki  ELCB is based on voltage sensing, but isn't this was old 1950s tech. Modern ELCB still use it?

[image]

Comment: I think ELCB, GFCI and RCD are alternate names for the same general type of device used in different jurisdictions.

Comment: But if you will read the internet. ELCB only protects from earth meaning if a person is between them. No protection whereas RCD can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is there a current differential sense coil inside this ELCB (Earth
> Leakage Circuit Breaker) just like GFCI or RCD?*

No there isn't if the device is a true old-fashioned ELCB. There will be a coil but that coil will be sensing current flow through the earth connection like this: -

[image]

The ELCB relies on an intact earth connection to the downstream equipment and an intact earth connection back to the fuse board. It is the forerunner of the GFCI or RCD: -

[image]

The great thing about the GFCI or RCD is that it doesn't require an intact earth connection to be able to infer an earth current. That's where the differential transformer plays its role.

ELCBs are old-tech now and not as safe as GFCIs or RCDs.

Comment: I wonder why most water heaters have ELCBs and not RCDs. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm maybe because water heaters are earthed by default hence the wire is present AND maybe elcbs are cheaper tech?

Comment: What happens if water heaters are not earthed? It's plastic enclosure. In my place. All tankless instant water heaters are not earthed and i have never seen one that is earthed.

Comment: I have no idea on your country's regulations for this type of apparatus. If no earth wire then use an RCD/GFCI.

Comment: I bought another tankless water heater, a stiebel eltron. They used RCCB/RCD already. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/522816/why-is-there-a-fuse-in-this-rccb-rcd/522820#522820  but in their ads they stll used the term ELCB. It will be better to use the more modern RCD term isnt it.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking me @Jtl

Comment: Just sharing they used RCD in latest models. I thought it was still old ELCD tech. I guess the industry got stuck with the old term.

Comment: @Jtl If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The pictured device is a current sensing RCD type ELCB

[image]

note  the trim level is given in millampreres
note also the two terminals each side (in the original photo) a voltage sensing ELCB would have three terminals each side.

[Kyokuto's website](http://www.kyokuto-elec.co.jp/?page_id=49) does not list this part, but does list some with similar part numbers. It also has this picture:

[image]

I doubt that this is 60 years old, the Chinese weren't making anything like this 50 years years ago.  I suspect that it's now old stock from a discontinued line.

Comment: Its used in present panasonic tankless water heaters..so its really an RCD? Why did they call it ELCB? According to wiki entry of it. An ELCB senses the voltage.

Comment: @jasen There is a technical difference between an ELCB and an RCD.

Comment: @Jtl I agree with wikipedia: "RCD/RCCB is the commonly used ELCB type."

Comment: Then Wiki is incorrect.

Comment: @Andyaka  the difference is that all RCD are ELCB  but not all ELCB  are RCDs.  if you have evidence to the contrarary please cite it.

Comment: I bought another tankless water heater, a stiebel eltron. They used RCCB/RCD already. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/522816/why-is-there-a-fuse-in-this-rccb-rcd/522820#522820  but in their ads they stll used the term ELCB. It will be better to use the more modern RCD term isnt it.